# How to change wide data into long data in R?

Tags: r

I'm a novice in R. If I have a data frame "DATA", now I want to change the original “DATA” into a new data frame arranged like “data”, What should I do?

```
> DATA<-data.frame(E1=c(131,135,136),
>               E2=c(215,216,217),
>               E3=c(315,316,317)) 
DATA
E1  E2  E3 
131 215 315 
135 216 316 
136 217 317

data：
Value E
131  E1
135  E1
136  E1
215  E2  
216  E2
217  E2
315  E3
316  E3
317  E3
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(DATA, cols = everything())`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I want to get “data” is completely in the order above. The order you get by this method is not what I want. Is there a better way?

Comment: You can always arrange the data by `E`. Or use `tidyr::gather(DATA, E, Value)`